# Best http header fix for IE8 flickering hover background-image, to allow it to cache the hover image in the same page view?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers

Take a look [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/QFHPb/) in IE8, if you have that installed.

Whenever you hover or unhover from the image, it is fetched again from the server. IE8 will not cache the image even in the same page. It is caused because IE doesn't see any cache headers on the image, and so decides it can't cache it.

Adding a caching header like `max-age:300` "solves" it for the given duration: A hover/unhover will last for 5 minutes without flickering.

This solution is not a good one, because of the time limit (flickering will return after 5 minutes), and because it actually hurts other browsers - if I understand correctly, they might flicker after the time elapses, where as today I didn't see any flickering on other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, even IE9 all work well without the header).

Sprites is another solution, which might in fact be the better overall solution - but suppose for a sec that before/in addition to implementing this, we want to find another, better HTTP header to send that will just fix IE, without imposing a specific cache limit within the same session. Essentially, I want the header to say "it's ok to cache this for the given page/session".

Is there such a beast?

Comment: Why do you care about IE8? Also, people who use ie8 LOVE the flickering thing

Comment: @RegisteredUser - funny.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that there is no workaround for your issue.
Only a special piece of code will eliminate the flickering.